# Covariance Matrix of Gaussian Model

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, covariance

How would the covariance matrix $\Sigma$ for P(T,Y) be calculated from an equation of the form:
$X:=\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$T:=X+\mathcal{N}(0,1)$
$Y:=X+T+\mathcal{N}(0,1)$

Edit: each $\mathcal{N}(0,I)$ is independent

Using the useful fact below, solving for the mean vector and diagonal values of $\Sigma$ of P(T,Y) is simple enough, however it isn't clear to me how one would solve for $\Sigma_{TY}$

Useful:
if $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X,\sigma_X^2)$, $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y^2)$, and $Z = X + Y$
then, $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X + \mu_Y,\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2)$

Thank you for any responses

Comment: Are your $\mathcal N(0,1)$ terms independent of everything else? Your useful fact only works when $X$ and $Y$ are independent (e.g. take $X$ to be $\mathcal N(0,1)$ and $Y=-X$)

Comment: Yes, $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is always independent of everything else*